# Уточнение ли в запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

> Первый двор отсекал любопытствующих, иногда размещал паломников, **да и
>   местных жителей**, в случае военной угрозы.

Может, всё - цепочка уточнений? И пусть запятые живут себе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Да и местных жителей** ― обособленный оборот с присоединительным союзом ДА И. Имеет значение добавочного сообщения.